# (Jackson 1.9.2) Getting @JsonIgnore to work: deserialization with mixin annotations and polymorphic types

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON String like (extracted this bit to show the issue)

```
{
    "$type": "com.example.StringProperty",
    "value": "hello world",
    "name": "text",
    "readOnly": false
}
```

into a hierarchy of classes that look like

```
public class Property
{
    public String name;
    public int    type;

    Property(String pName, int pType) { name = pName; type = pType; }
}

public class StringProperty extends Property 
{
    public String value;        
    StringProperty(String pName, String pValue) {
        super(pName, String);
        value = pValue;
    }       
}
```

using the following mixin annotations

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="$type")
abstract public class PropertyMixin
{
    @JsonProperty
    public String name;
    //@JsonIgnore
    //public boolean readOnly;
    @JsonProperty
    public int type;

    PropertyMixin(@JsonProperty("name") String pName, @JsonProperty("type") int pType)
    {
    }
}

abstract public class StringPropertyMixin
{
    @JsonProperty
    public String value;
    //@JsonIgnore
    //public boolean readOnly;

    @JsonCreator
    public StringPropertyMixin(@JsonProperty("name") String pName, @JsonProperty("value") String value)
    {
    }
}
```

With Jackson 1.9.2, the error I am getting is

`Unrecognized field "readOnly" (Class com.example.StringProperty), not marked as ignorable`

I tried using `@JsonIgnore`, but that did not help (check the locations of the code I commented out to see how I tried it). I am probably missing something, but I think another set of eyes need to look at it and help me.

This is how the deserialization environment looks like:

```
        objectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

        MixinRegistrations module = new MixinRegistrations();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

and mixin module looks like

```
@Override
public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
{
    context.setMixInAnnotations(Property.class, PropertyMixin.class);
    context.setMixInAnnotations(StringProperty.class, StringPropertyMixin.class);
}
```

I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

PS: I do not know if this makes a difference but the JSON is being generated by a library written in .Net Framework v4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Jackson is having problems because the method that you have delegated as a creator does not have a parameter for the `readOnly` field. So rather than silently ignore this missing parameter Jackson is throwing an error (good behaviour). Try using the [`JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown) annotation. I've not had need to use if before, but for deserialisation you can explicitly denote fields that are not required by the creator.

Oh, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168095/jackson-ignore-json-configuration-value) appears related as well.

**Edit:**
[Another question that the asker found that was useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438474/what-is-wrong-with-my-jsoncreator-and-mixin-annotation)

Comment: Yes, you can add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) if that's the behavior you want

Comment: @Dunes: How does `@JsonIgnoreProperties` help if `@JsonIgnore` is not working in this situation? It looks like `@JsonIgnoreProperties` just an extension of `@JsonIgnore` to multiple values.

Comment: I understood why `@JsonIgnore` did not work in my case but `@JsonIgnoreProperties` works fine after reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438474/what-is-wrong-with-my-jsoncreator-and-mixin-annotation). Thanks for pointing out `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

Comment: @alokoko Difference is that `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is added at class-level, and can be used to ignore JSON properties by name; whereas `@JsonIgnore` only ignores specific property, and you must have a field or setter/getter to attach it to.

Comment: @StaxMan: the part "and you must have a field or setter/getter to attach it to" is important. What I also had missed initially was that this statement should read as "and you must have a field or setter/getter to attach it to in the target class", since I already had that field in my mixin class, but it did not work. I got it after reading another reply from you in [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438474/what-is-wrong-with-my-jsoncreator-and-mixin-annotation).

Comment: @alokoko Glad you were able to find a solution. Will add the links to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your problem is NOT that class has a property Jackson does not recognize, but rather that JSON has a property. As such you may want to read [this wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown).

As mentioned, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` would work here, since adding that annotation to a class does not require a field or setter, unlike `@JsonIgnore` does. Plus it can be used to ignore any and all unknown properties.

Comment: Thanks for the link. 30 seconds before your answer, I posted a comment about how I understood how things worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"propX", "propY"})
```

Would work just fine at class level!